# Search inside table MySql database with JSB

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, netbeans, web-applications

I'm a beginner programmer, I already build page for data entry and page show all entries, but now I want to show specific row inside the table, which code can help me?

My table columns: fullname - email - Phone - education
I want to search by email to show the other data in one page.

I found this code on internet:

```js
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<% Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <%!
            public class Showit {

                String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/regdata";
                String USERNAME = "root";
                String PASSWORD = "admin";

                Connection conn = null;
                PreparedStatement selectRegister = null;
                ResultSet resultSet = null;

                public Showit() {
                    try {
                        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
                        selectRegister = conn.prepareStatement(
                                "SELECT a.fullname, a.email,"
                                + " FROM mainr a,"
                                + "WHERE a.fullname = ?"
                                + "AND a.email = ?");

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                public ResultSet getShowit(String fullname, String email) {
                    try {
                        selectRegister.setString(1, fullname);
                        selectRegister.setString(2, email);
                        resultSet = selectRegister.executeQuery();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return resultSet;
                }
            }

        %>
        <%
            String fullname = new String();
            String email = new String();
            if (request.getParameter("fullname") != null) {
                fullname = request.getParameter("fullname");

            }
            if (request.getParameter("email") != null) {
                fullname = request.getParameter("email");

            }

            Showit showit = new Showit();
            ResultSet showits = showit.getShowit(fullname, email);

        %>
        <table border="1">

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Full Name</td>
                    <td>Email</td>
                    <td>Title</td>
                </tr>
                <% while (showits.next()) {%>
                <tr>
                    <td><%= showits.getString("fullname")%></td>
                    <td><%= showits.getString("email")%></td>
                    <td><%= showits.getString("Phone")%></td>
                </tr>
                <% }%>
            </tbody>
        </table>


    </body>
</html>
```

which connect with this page:

```js
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Scanner" %>
<% Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Search</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="search" action="display.jsp" method="POST">
            <table border="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Full Name</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="fullname" value="" size="50" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>E-Mail</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email" value=""  size="50" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <input type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

but it's not work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be with this line:

```
fullname = request.getParameter("email");
```

Note that you are assigning the email parameter to the fullname variable.

Comment: I fix it to email = request.getParameter("email");

Answer (score 0):

first what i see is that the Query is wrong. Remove the , after the table alias "a" (here line 2) like this:

```
 "SELECT a.fullname, a.email,"
          + " FROM mainr a"
          + "WHERE a.fullname = ?"
          + "AND a.email = ?");
```

Comment: Still "Error: java.lang.NullPointerException"

Comment: there also must a space at end of each line in the query else you get a String like this: SELECT a.fullname, a.email, FROM mainr aWHERE a.fullname = ?AND a.email = ?

Comment: I put spaces before it, but still error. I think my code is wrong

Answer (score 0):

There is also an issue here:

```
<td><%= showits.getString("Phone")%></td>
```

You did not include Phone in the SELECT statement, so it will not exist in the ResultSet.